# How would I go about storing a global count variable?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Suppose I wanted to have a running count of every document in my database.

For instance, starting with an empty database; calling `Collections.insert` would go check increment a global count variable, and then store its value as a field in the document.

Some sample input would be read as follows on the db. 
Eg. count: 1 name: First
    count: 2 name: Second

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection to keep track of the counter. Let's call it `counters`.

Prior to inserting a document in your collection, call `find_and_modify` in the `counters` collection to atomically increment the counter and return its value. Store this value on the document and then insert it.

This procedure is well described in the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#a-counters-collection). Be aware that it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents, as stated in those docs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple, if you are storing the global counter in a Meteor session variable (which are global to the client) try this:

```
// doc is your record. Make other changes here too: 
// i.e. doc.answer_text = "Ask Mork, Na-nu, Na-nu!";

doc.count = Session.get('myCounter');
doc.count++;

Stuff.insert( doc ); // Collection name is Stuff.
```

To check if the current user changes AND reset the counter:

```
Session.set('myUserId', Meteor.userId); 
if (Session.get('myUserId') !== Meteor.userId)
    Session.set('myCounter', 0);
```

If you simply want to increment a counter stored in the collection:

```
Stuff.insert( doc, {$inc: {mycounter: 1} }  );
```

Comment: The Session variable is not a global among all the users, it is only global to a single client. So Session.get("myCounter") unfortunately will not work.

Comment: @Louis93 According to the Meteor documentation Session variables are exactly what you are asking for "only global to a single client", you would just need to reset it if one of the clients logs in as a different user: http://docs.meteor.com/#session, see my answer below: